# Query Queried Table Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel-5

I was wondering if we could query already queried table. Like this:

```
$results = Table::where('name','like', '%'.$request['name'].'%')->get();
$results = $results::where('surname', 'like', '%'.$request['surname'.'%'])->get();
```

I try to do something like this, because I have many options to query from table, and some of them may be empty. So in order not to check all possibilities, and writing different queries, it would be easier in this way. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $result variable is in fact a Laravel Collection, so you have a lot of option to work with a Collection including its own where() function.

Imho I will go with this code:

```
$query = Table::where('name','like', '%'.$request['name'].'%');
$results = $query->get();
$results2 = $query->where('surname', 'like', '%'.$request['surname'.'%'])->get();
```